# sqlite trigger insert convert to json

Tags: json, sqlite, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert

I'm using SQLite 3.37.2 through Python 3.10.5, and editing the database with DBeaver - maybe it's not always at its best when reporting database errors.

Anyway, I want to convert a text (JSON) in SQLite proper JSON format upon insertion, by calling its `json()` function.

I thought about adding a simple trigger to handle that, but I can't figure out what's wrong in my syntax:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t1_before_insert AFTER INSERT ON t1 FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN  
        SET NEW.json:=json(NEW.json);
    END
;
```

This is the latest version I attempted, I always get an error like

```
SQL error or missing database (near "SET": syntax error)
```

I tried:

- `SET NEW.json:=json(NEW.json)`
- `SET NEW.json=json(NEW.json)`
- `SELECT NEW.json:=json(NEW.json)`
- using an `AFTER INSERT` trigger

but none worked.

Comment: There's absolutely no point to that. JSON is only stored in the database as plain text.

Comment: @Shawn Almost, since it ["verifies that its argument X is a valid JSON string and returns a minified version"](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#the_json_function) and I quite like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the value of a column of the new row like that.

You must update the table in an `AFTER INSERT` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t1_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON t1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN  
  UPDATE t1
  SET json = json(NEW.json)
  WHERE t1.id = NEW.id;
END;
```

Change `id` to the table's primary key.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=af8a60b665cf506a981440be74aa34be).

Comment: Oh, I just saw that I posted an `AFTER INSERT`, while I originally wanted (and tried to) write a `BEFORE INSERT`: does yours hold true even in that case? I can't update the being inserted row?

Comment: @watery in a BEFORE INSERT trigger the rowid of the new row is not known, this is why I use an AFTER INSERT trigger.